# Dynamical Update data Javascript Highchar

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I write dynamical in a JSON file (`datos.json in the code`) and I need make a automatic update data. The problem is when a I run the code, don't update the data. Why?? I look whit `network chrome dev tools` and I don't see any error.

This is the code

```
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });

    var chart;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];

                    $.getJSON('static/data.json', function (data) {
               series.addPoint(data);
                    }, 1000); 
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: [1,1],
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed setInterval in your load event. It should be:

```
 setInterval(function(){
       $.getJSON('static/data.json', function (data) {
           series.addPoint(data);
       });
 },1000);
```

What returs your json I mean static/data.json ?

Comment: Hi. I change the code but now I have and other problem. The graph is dynamical updated but add white points valueless (don't the point in the file), and though the file don't change, the graph contiuns add valueless point. Why?

Comment: Have you sorted data via x ascending? any live demo?

Comment: [here](http://senpy-auka.rhcloud.com/grafico) you can see the code run, and can see the problem. I don't know what is `x ascending`. Thanks

Comment: I mean that data shoud be sorted, by x ascending. as I see you have incorrect data becase you have [[1,1],[2,4],[5.5]] which is not correct because should be [[1,1],[2,4],5.5] or [[1,1],[2,4],[5,5]]

Comment: I change the data to `[[1,1],[2,4],[5,5]]`, but have the same error.I try use series.setData() and change the data! But now, the JSON file is read only the first time, then is read from cache. Who I can do to read always the file from the source and don't from cache?? Thanks